# Django: serving ADMIN media files

Tags: django, routes, path, media, admin

I've been successfully serving media files for the normal MEDIA files, but when I tried serving admin media files, I failed. please kindly help me locating the problem, as I've tried to troubleshoot the problem for several hours already with no luck (been googling too and read the django doc about serving static files as well).

The error as I tried to access localhost:8000/media/a.gif is as following:

> Page not found:
>   f:\python25\lib\site-packages\django/contrib/admin/media\a.gif

I put the admin media files in directory named "media", while I put the normal media files in directory named "static". I'm on Windows, too.

Here's how I serve the ordinary media files in urls.py:

```
# serve static files
from django.conf import settings
if settings.ENVIRONMENT==settings.ENV_DEVELOPMENT:
    urlpatterns += patterns("django.views",
        url(r"%s(?P<path>.*)$" % settings.MEDIA_URL[1:], "static.serve", {"document_root": settings.MEDIA_ROOT,})
    )
```

And my settings.py (only the important pieces):

```
import project_path
MEDIA_ROOT = project_path.MEDIA.replace('\\','/')
MEDIA_URL = '/static/'
ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX = '/media/'
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    project_path.TEMPLATE.replace('\\','/'),
)
```

And my project_path.py:

```
import sys
from os.path import dirname, join
ROOT = dirname(__file__)
APP = join(ROOT, "apps")
TEMPLATE = join(ROOT, "templates")
MEDIA = join(ROOT, "static")
ADMIN_MEDIA = join(ROOT, "media")
```

Any hints?

or maybe at least please share how do you serve your admin media files (without changing any files from the web server, but only via the django source code)

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Did you ever resolve this?  I am having a similar experience working on Mac with Django 1.1, serving normal media files works but not for the admin...

Comment: The reason the url settings don't work, is because `django/core/management/commands/runserver.py` together with `django.core.servers.basehttp` setup a WSGI handler for `ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX`. It handles the request before the URLconf is hit

Answer (score 32):

Your answer is that unless `ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX` explicitly sets a domain
the runserver command will serve out the admin media files from contrib.admin.

I got burned by this *magic* behaviour, too. There was a ticket for this ([Ticket #8336](http://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/8336)), but the design decision was to leave the convenience and confusion as it is.

So to serve your admin media (for using grappelli or whatever admin skin you want to use) from your directories with the `runserver` command you have to use something like:

```
MEDIA_ROOT =  os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'media/')
ADMIN_MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'admin-media/')
MEDIA_URL = '/site-media/'
ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX = 'http:/localhost:8000/admin-media/'
```

I hope I am resurrecting the correct question here. Apologies in advance.

Comment: Magic convenience behaviours. Thanks Django! How about sensible defaults in settings.py instead? (sigh)... thanks for this Phoku!

Comment: I think there is some logic in their decision as maybe most of the users don't change and there is already so many settings to take care of. As a beginner this kind of conveniences are nice to have.

Comment: The "magic" is more of a clever workaround, it curcumvents the `path.startswith(base_url)` check in `AdminMediaHandler._should_handle()`. Hence, you skip the WSGI handler, and enter the normal URLconf :)

Answer (score 3):

It is advised to run the  dev server a little bit different [1]
python manage.py runserver mydomain.com:8000 --adminmedia=/path/to/your/admin/media/

[1] http://code.google.com/p/django-grappelli/wiki/Installation

Comment: That must be django-grappelli specific. With vanilla Django 1.2, I get `error: no such option: --adminmedia`

Comment: No, the explanation is [here][1]: "If the staticfiles contrib app is enabled (default in new projects) the runserver command will be overriden with an own runserver command which doesn't have the --adminmedia option due to deprecation." [1]: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/

Answer (score 2):

Try

(r'^admin_media/(.*)', 'django.views.static.serve', {'document_root' : 'django/contrib/admin/media/', 'show_indexes' : True}),

in your urls.py file. And change your

```
ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX = '/admin_media/'
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, but it still doesn't work :) I typed http://localhost:8000/admin_media/a.gif in the broswer url and the result is: 
Page not found: f:\python25\lib\site-packages\django/contrib/admin/media\a.gif

Answer (score 2):

I just fixed a similar bug in my test site.  ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX and MEDIA_URL should never be the same, see the following note in the [docs](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#setting-ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX):

> Make sure to use a trailing slash, and
>   to have this be different from the
>   MEDIA_URL setting (since the same URL
>   cannot be mapped onto two different
>   sets of files).

Answer (score 1):

Try changing:

`ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX = '/static/media/'`

This assumes that your MEDIA_ROOT/media/ directory contains the admin media folder (which is what I understood from your question).

Comment: thanks for the answer, but it still doesn't work :)

I typed http://localhost:8000/static/media/a.gif in the broswer url and the result is:

Page not found: f:\python25\lib\site-packages\django/contrib/admin/media\a.gif

Comment: I think I'll try to recreate the project from scratch again using the conventional admin media examples :) thanks for the answers

Answer (score 1):

Since staticfiles inclusion into trunk, (circa 1.3 I believe), the ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX magic is no longer used.

Nowadays, runserver assumes your STATIC_URL + 'admin/'. It secretly and silently intercepts your requests, ignores all your urlconf's, and tries to make you go mad.

Comment: I found the opposite - with django 1.3 if I didn't have ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX = posixpath.join(STATIC_URL, "admin/") (ie, if I just didn't have ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX set at all) then runserver didn't serve my admin media correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Try to Use STATICFILES_DIRS as blow

```
# Additional locations of static files
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    # Put strings here, like "/home/html/static" or "C:/www/django/static".
    # Always use forward slashes, even on Windows.
    # Don't forget to use absolute paths, not relative paths.
    ("images", os.path.join(STATIC_ROOT,'images').replace('\\','/')),
    ("css",    os.path.join(STATIC_ROOT,'css').replace('\\','/')),
    ("js",     os.path.join(STATIC_ROOT,'js').replace('\\','/')),
)
```

Have a goodluck!

Comment: STATICFILES_DIRS = (
        ("media", os.path.join(STATIC_ROOT,'media').replace('\\','/')),
    )