# Django admin has no style

Tags: django, django-admin

I have just moved my django site on my staging server, and the admin side of the site has no styling with it, when previously in local development it was fine, I read somewhere that I need to create a symbolic link, I did that by doing this

```
sudo ln -s /var/www/sico/htdocs /usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/
```

but that has done nothing is there anything else that I can try?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1081596/django-serving-admin-media-files.

Answer (score 10):

Depending on your web server setup, you can do it one of two ways:

## Symlinking

In your website's root folder, you should create a symbolic link to your Django admin media directory, with the name name as the `ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX` in your Django app's settings. By default this is `/media/`, so in your web root folder, create a symlink called `media` to `/usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/media`. (Note the trailing `media` on the end of the symlink, which is missing from your own example -- the Django admin media is located in a `media` subdirectory`in`contrib/admin`).

## Apache Alias

If your production server is Apache, and you can change the root configuration, you can use `mod_alias` to set up the path to Django admin media. Again, assuming that your `ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX` is `/media/`, you can set up an alias like so:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  Alias /media/ /usr/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/media/
</VirtualHost>
```

This way, all requests under the path `/media/` will be resolved to that directory.

A similar technique exists for most other servers, such as Lighttpd or nginx; consult your server's documentation if you don't use Apache.

---

The solution using Apache's `mod_alias` is probably best for deployment, but the symlinking approach works just as well too.

The reason your app worked on your staging server is most likely because it was running with Django's internal web server, which can automatically resolve the path to the admin media directory.

Comment: hi, may i know where does "<VirtualHost *:80>
  Alias /media/ /usr/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/media/
</VirtualHost>" go? does it go into the http.conf file?

Comment: For the curious: yes, the virtualhost entry goes in Apache's httpd.conf file.

Comment: @mipadi I think for django 1.4 you have to do `Alias /static/admin C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\static\admin`

Answer (score 1):

I think you've created the symlink the wrong way round - your command has created a `htdocs` symlink in ..../contrib/admin/

What you need is something like

```
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/ /var/www/sico/htdocs/X
```

Where `X` is whatever you need to get to your ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX. I think the default would be `admin/media`

Hope that helps