# Django 1.3 - How do I update contrib.admin to use jQuery 1.5+ (It's currently 1.4)

Tags: jquery, django, django-admin

Like the title says, Im trying to bump my jQuery version up to 1.5+ (so that I can get past an issue with django-markitup AJAX call VS django's CSRF protection).

Looking at the contrib.admin.templates.base.html I see that JavaScript gets included dynamically, not im not sure how/where to add this and how to do so without breaking things going forward.

Comment: I discovered that Im using a Django App that has inserted a Google JavaScript API URI, pointing to jQuery1.4. I thought this was part of Django's contrib.admin app but I grepped my virtualenv directory and discovered that ``django-markitup`` was loading this Google-based JS resource which I can override in my ``settings.py`` with a simple ``JQUERY_URL = 'http://...'``.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8945831/how-can-i-update-jquery-version-in-django-admin

Answer (score 0):

Default `js` files are in [`django/contrib/admin/media/js`](https://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/contrib/admin/media/js) *(jquery,...)*.

You can also change the admin media files location ([*Django: serving ADMIN media files*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1081596/django-serving-admin-media-files)) and use whatever version of `jquery` you like (it's better to keep default `django` files untouched).