# Django gets tinymce by two different paths

Tags: django, tinymce

When I go to main site page, requests for tinymce are:

```
"GET /media/js/tiny_mce/textareas.js HTTP/1.1" 200 2007
"GET /media/js/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js HTTP/1.1" 200 207773
```

because I use MEDIA_URL for tinymce stuff. But when I go to /admin pages requests are:

```
"GET /static/js/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js HTTP/1.1" 304 0
"GET /static/js/tiny_mce/textareas.js HTTP/1.1" 200 2007
```

Why? And where to correct this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fragment of \venv\Lib\site-packages\tinymce\settings.py:

```
if 'staticfiles' in settings.INSTALLED_APPS or 'django.contrib.staticfiles' in settings.INSTALLED_APPS:
    JS_URL = getattr(settings, 'TINYMCE_JS_URL',os.path.join(settings.STATIC_URL, 'tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js'))
    JS_ROOT = getattr(settings, 'TINYMCE_JS_ROOT',os.path.join(settings.STATIC_ROOT, 'tiny_mce'))
else:
    JS_URL = getattr(settings, 'TINYMCE_JS_URL','%sjs/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js' % settings.MEDIA_URL)
    JS_ROOT = getattr(settings, 'TINYMCE_JS_ROOT', os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, 'js/tiny_mce'))
```

AFAIR 'django.contrib.staticfiles' is included in INSTALLED_APPS by default. Therefore tinymce should be located in static dir. Instructions about putting tinymce in media directory misled me.

Answer (score 0):

Newer versions (1.4) of django [use the static files app to handle admin media](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.4/#django-contrib-admin) (i.e. `/static/...`):

> Starting in Django 1.4, the admin's static files also follow this convention [using static files], to make the files easier to deploy. In previous versions of Django, it was also common to define an ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX setting to point to the URL where the admin's static files live on a Web server. This setting has now been deprecated and replaced by the more general setting STATIC_URL.

So, if you are < 1.4, you can use [`ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#admin-media-prefix) to change the path used by the admin though (check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1081596/django-serving-admin-media-files) question to make sure you see how it works). Otherwise, adapt your app to [make use of static files](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/)

Comment: Searched for "STATIC_URL" in all files and found answer myself.

Comment: Ah, I didn't think it was down to the tiny mce implementation - don't forget to accept your own answer